# Print is not showing result when executing this simple socket connection code in python. Why is the print not showing result?

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following client/server python code. The print line from the server where i used f-string interpolation does not show anything when the code is executed and I would like to know why?
I followed this tutorial and on their end the print line shows result.
tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm
line: Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 48437)

my server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Server.py
# Import socket module
import socket               
# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket()
# Get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()
# Reserve a port number for the socket service
port = 22226
# Bind the host address and the port number
s.bind((host, port))        
# Listens for the client connections made for the socket.
# The argument shows maximum number of queued connections and it is 1 at minimum
s.listen(5)                 
while True:
   # Establish connection with client.
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print(f"Got connection from {addr}")
   c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

my client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# client.py
# Import socket module
import socket               
# Create a socket object
s = socket.socket()
# Get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()
# Reserve a port number for the socket service
port = 22226           
# Connect the host address and the port number
s.connect((host, port))
# Read at most 1024 bytes
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()                     # Close the socket when done
```

Comment: the connection works but the only thing that gets printed is  thank you for connecting. I also want the line 'Got connection from ...' and that doesn't get printed. I was wondering could it be that in newer python version print statements don't execute when using sockets?

Comment: `Thank you for connecting` shouldn't be printed on the server, it gets sent to the client.

Comment: Your code works for me. In the server window I saw `Got connection from ('192.168.3.3', 52092)` and in the client window I saw `b'Thank you for connecting'`.

Comment: How did you run it?  because I cannot see the line Got connection from ('192.168.3.3', 52092)

Comment: Ok I run my server code using power shell and it did show the Got connection from print line. The problem was when running it using Git bash and it would be interesting to know why that happens.

Comment: I just opened two Terminal windows on my Mac, one for server, one for client.